# Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() doesn't return any value

Tags: asp.net, sql, code-behind, sqldatasource

Why the following code doesn't return any data? There are values in the database for `Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()`

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="owner_information" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Viewtest] WHERE [IDuser] = @IDowner">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="IDowner" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    owner_information.SelectParameters["IDowner"].DefaultValue = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();  
}
```

Comment: Should it not be `HttpContext.Current`?

Comment: Debug your code, step by step, to see what are the values on the User, Identity, etc...